# What are the most-valuable research fields to explore nowadays concerning game AI?

Tags: ai

I'm having some troubles coming up with a subject for my master's degree thesis. I'd like to know what areas of research are valuable at this time (and the near future) so I can narrow my search and idea-creation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour trees are a big thing in the industry right now, but from an academic perspective there hasn't been too much research into them, as far as I'm aware.

Parallelism with AI systems is an interesting area too, but I'm not too sure on what has been done with it.

Check out [AIGameDev.com](http://aigamedev.com/) and in particular [this link](http://aigamedev.com/open/editorial/open-challenges-fps/). It details a number of current open challenges with regards to FPS games.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a more general question last week. [This answer should be helpful.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11615/what-research-areas-exist-in-game-programming/11625#11625)

I asked what the research areas are too, but I think a better question is, "Where can I find some resources showing the current research trends". This answer covers that fairly well.